# Is it possible to detect the load of an applet?

Tags: html, applet, safari-extension, onbeforeload

I'm working on a Safari extension, and I'd like to detect when `<applet>`s are going to load (the `onbeforeload` event) on a page. However, there seems to be no such event for these.

How should I do it? Transform all `<applet>` tags to `<object>` tags and then intercept their `onbeforeload` events? I think it would break the `document.applets` collection, so it's not a very cool solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `<applet>` is not very subtle, I just hook on `DOMContentLoaded` and `DOMNodeInserted` to catch `<applet>`s as soon as I can. It's butchy but I don't think I can do any better.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that using JavaScript. The applet element in HTML DOM has an `isActive()` property. You can test that on intervals. You can find several basic examples [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0176.html).

Comment: Hm, I realize I didn't ask for the right thing. The event I really want is `onbeforeload` rather than `onload`. Thanks though. Have this +1 anyways.